# How to handle iOS Sprite Kit beta questions, what tags should be associated?

Tags: discussion

With more and more questions being asked about iOS 10 and some of the new functionalities with Sprite Kit,  how should we be addressing these issues?  I have come across a number of posts asking about new methods that are being introduced to Sprite Kit, but because they are in beta, they do not have much documentation associated with it.  Should these questions be tagged with `swift3`,  should a new tag be created called `spritekit-beta`, or maybe tag it with `ios10`? I am not sure how Sprite Kit gets versioned, I do not see any way of distinguishing which version to use but I do know if we had some better way to differentiate the iterations of Sprite Kit, it may be easier to help answer questions in this category.